# Проверка корректности email регулярным выражением под разные браузеры

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Собственно написал регулярку, которая проверяет корректность введеного email-а. Одна на некоторых браузерах возникают ошибки. Возможно, есть какие-то нюансы?

```
var reg = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;
let email = $('#inpEmail').val();
if (reg.test(email) == false){
    alert("Заполните Email");
    return;
}
```

Comment: `"Василий Пупкин"@mail.ru`

Comment: @Akina и? Проверка не проходит. У нас же русские символы нельзя вводить в email

Comment: У кого это - у вас? по поводу мыльных адресов целый RFC имеется, и согласно ему написанный выше адрес совершенно валиден. Там вообще столько вольностей, что регулярка по проверке валидности будет размером с хорошую повесть.. плюнь. Тупо резани адрес хоста, что после последней собаки, проверь его на существование в DNS, да успокойся. А имя вообще не трогай - может, регистрирующийся является админом почтового сервера, тогда он получит вообще письмо на любую дурь, которую напишет в имени...

Comment: Вы правы) Не разу не видел email с русскими символами(потому и удивился) и гугл подсказал, что регулярка RFC будет супер гигантской)